# Nested for loops - Order of output for strings in objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class, object

I just can't figure this one out. So, I have the class team and the class player. Player objects are stored within their team(object).

The teams themselves are stored in the listofteams object.

Every time a team or a player is created, I want javascript to loop through the list and append every team with its players. E.g.:

TEAM 1 -
Player 1 -
Player 2

TEAM 2 -
Player 3

Unfortunately, the current output looks like this:

TEAM 1 - 
Player 1 -
Player 2 -
Player 3

TEAM 2 -
*Player 3 belongs to team 2 but is printed beneath team 1.*

**How do I manage to loop through my objects and arrays, so the players are appended beneath the team they actually belong to?**

Here are the classes:

```
 class Team {
     constructor(teamname, teamleague ) {
         this.teamname = teamname;
         this.teamleague = teamleague;
         this.players = [];
         this._id = this.generateid();
     }
     generateid() {
         return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
           var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
           return v.toString(16);
         });
       }

 };

 class Player {
     constructor (playerteam, playerfirstname, playerlastname, playernumber) {
     this.playerteam = playerteam;
     this.playerfirstname = playerfirstname;
     this.playerlastname = playerlastname;
     this.playernumber = playernumber;
     this.team_id = $('#select-native-2 option:selected').attr("id");
     }
 };
```

Here's my loop:

```
function writeall () {
    $("#teamappendarea").empty();

    for(element in listOfTeams){ 
        $("#teamappendarea").append("<p>" + listOfTeams[element].teamname + "</p>");
            for (var i = 0; i < listOfTeams[element].players.length; i++){

                $("#teamappendarea").append("<p>" + listOfTeams[element].players[i].playerlastname + "</p>");
            }
        } 
};
```

A console.log of the teams show

```js
{
  "981929ef-c918-4e59-9296-49581bcba144": {
    "teamname": "team1",
    "teamleague": "",
    "players": [{
      "playerteam": "team1",
      "playerfirstname": "Player1",
      "playerlastname": "Player1",
      "playernumber": "1111",
      "team_id": "981929ef-c918-4e59-9296-49581bcba144"
    }, {
      "playerteam": "team2",
      "playerfirstname": "Player2",
      "playerlastname": "Player2",
      "playernumber": "1111",
      "team_id": "7d2ab469-a33a-4246-94d1-fdc98886f0c1"
    }],
    "_id": "981929ef-c918-4e59-9296-49581bcba144"
  },
  "7d2ab469-a33a-4246-94d1-fdc98886f0c1": {
    "teamname": "team2",
    "teamleague": "",
    "players": [],
    "_id": "7d2ab469-a33a-4246-94d1-fdc98886f0c1"
  }
}
```

Comment: What shows if you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(listOfTeams))`

Comment: {"981929ef-c918-4e59-9296-49581bcba144":{"teamname":"team1","teamleague":"","players":[{"playerteam":"team1","playerfirstname":"Player1","playerlastname":"Player1","playernumber":"1111","team_id":"981929ef-c918-4e59-9296-49581bcba144"},{"playerteam":"team2","playerfirstname":"Player2","playerlastname":"Player2","playernumber":"1111","team_id":"7d2ab469-a33a-4246-94d1-fdc98886f0c1"}],"_id":"981929ef-c918-4e59-9296-49581bcba144"},"7d2ab469-a33a-4246-94d1-fdc98886f0c1":{"teamname":"team2","teamleague":"","players":[],"_id":"7d2ab469-a33a-4246-94d1-fdc98886f0c1"}}

Comment: in that case I added player 2 to team 2.

Comment: I just realized something when I looked at my console log closely. Apparently my team/player assignment function doesn't work properly anymore. I've probably changed so much in the meantime and figured out the loop but messed up the process while doing so. I'll have a close look at that.